# get specific data from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make a simple code that will get specific data from database based on  the user email.

for example, the user will enter his email in the text field and press the button fetch to get his own information.

I made this code but it doesn't work:

```
enter your email: <input type = "text"  name = "email" size="30"/>   
<input type = "submit"  name = "fetch" size="30" value="fetch" />  
<?php  
mysql_connect("localhost","name","pass");
mysql_select_db("table_Name");
if(isset($_POST['fetch']))
{
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$query = "SELECT * FROM table_Name WHERE user_email = '$email'"; 
$run = mysql_query($query );

if (mysql_num_rows($run) > 0)
{
$_SESSION['email']= $email;   

echo 'your information'.$email;   
}
else 
{
echo "<script>alert('wrong email!')</script>";     
}
}

?>
```

Comment: you are all sorts of open for sql injections

Comment: Hey, there. You should look into using Prepared statements or the mysqli_ functions. Your code will be safer, and the mysql_ functions will soon be removed from PHP. No use in learning old, outdated stuff right? Plus, your code will be much more secure.

Comment: Can you be more specific than "doesn't work?"

Comment: Note that you are assuming that the query was successful. You should consider adding an `or die(mysql_error())` statement to the end of the `mysql_query()` statement so that you can see if the query is failing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a form on your file. Like this:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<input type = "text"  name = "email" size="30"/>   
<input type = "submit"  name = "fetch" size="30" value="fetch" />
</form>
```

I suggest at least adding this also to validate email inputs:

```
$email = $_POST["email"];
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {die()};
```

Comment: If this was what you were missing please accept the answer :)